# how to find coordinate of unknown point given the distance against N known points

Tags: matrices

I have a problem where I already know the coordinates of $N$ points $(a_1,a_2,a_3,....)$ in 3D space. I have a new point, say $x$. I only know the distances from $x$ to the known $N$ points. Is there an efficient method to find the coordinates of $x$?

If all of the distances are error-free, I think I can randomly pick $3$ known points and compute the coordinates of $x$. But the distances are not error-free, i.e. if I use different points as reference, the coordinates of $x$ may differ a lot.

So I want to use all of those $N$ distances to compute the coordinates of $x$. Can anyone give some solution or suggestions?

Comment: In general one needs the distance to $4$ points in general position to determine a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$, not just $3$: If $x$ has prescribed distances to points $a_0, a_1, a_2$, then so does the image of $x$ under reflection in any plane containing those three points.

Comment: @Travis,Great, thanks for point out my error.  For the N points problem, do you have any suggestions

Comment: Sorry, no, it's quite a complicated problem, I think. It could probably stand to be specified more precisely, too---given that there are errors, what do you mean by the best estimate for $x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~dattorro/EDM.pdf) chapter from Jon Dattoro's *Convex optimization & Euclidean distance geometry* provides an explicit construction of your desired point (up to congruence) as follows:

As you have the co-ordinates of the original vectors, you can naturally convert your list into a list of (Euclidean) distances $d_{ij}$ between each pair $a_i, a_j$, for $1 \leq i \leq j \leq N$. Then, denoting the distances to your unknown point from each $a_i$ as $d_{ix}=d_{xi}$, we form the (symmetric, hollow) *Euclidean distance matrix* (actually, it remains to be verified that this is actually a Euclidean distance matrix, see the criteria in the above link)

$$E =\begin{bmatrix}
    d_{11} & d_{12} & d_{13} & \dots  & d_{1N} & d_{1x} \\
    d_{21} & d_{22} & d_{23} & \dots  & d_{2N} & d_{2x} \\
    d_{31} & d_{32} & d_{33} & \dots  & d_{3N} & d_{3x} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
    d_{N1} & d_{N2} & d_{N3} & \dots  & d_{NN} & d_{Nx} \\
    d_{x1} & d_{x2} & d_{x3} & \dots  & d_{xN} & d_{xx} 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then, depending on how you want your points reconstructed, you can follow any of the methods described in (the initial reference). I'll briefly detail the *geometrically centred* version: First, we define

$$
V = I_{N+1} - \frac{1}{N+1}{\bf 1 1}^T = \frac{1}{N+1}\begin{bmatrix}
    N & -1 & \dots  & -1 \\
    -1 & N & \dots  & -1 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    -1 & -1 & \dots  & N
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Then, diagonalise $-VEV$ to yield $Q \Lambda Q^T$ ($Q$ being the eigenvector matrix, and $\Lambda$ being the diagonal eigenvalue matrix). Finally, the list of points $a_i$, including $x$ (again, up to congruence) is given by

$$
\big[a_1 - \alpha_c, a_2 - \alpha_c, \cdots, a_{N+1} - \alpha_c\big] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\Lambda}Q^T, 
$$

where $\alpha_c$ is the geometric center of the points $a_i$ (including $x$).

Note that rank$\Lambda$ (=rank$VEV$) give the dimension of the space which the $a_i$ embed into - in general, this gives a system of equations in the $N$ variables $d_{ix}$ which determines whether the new collection of points (including $x$) sits again in $\mathbb{R}^3$, or a higher dimension (of course, pending whether the distance values are realisable or not).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method though it is not very pretty.

I will assume in the following that the list of points and distances is correct - that is that there exists some point which is of approximately the appropriate distance from each point (so for example we aren't trying to find a point which is distance $1$ from both the origin and the point $(0,0,10)$).

First choose some $4$ points out of your known points list which do not all lie in the same plane (if this condition does not exist, then as Travis notes there is not a unique solution). Let these points be $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_4$ with corresponding distances $d_1$, $d_2$, $d_3$, and $d_4$.

Next construct spheres of radii $d_1$, $d_2$, and $d_3$ around the points $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ respectively (note we are only making $3$ spheres). Now find the points of intersection of these spheres - even with slight error there should be $2$ solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$.

Finally compare the distance between $x_4$ and $y_1$ and the distance between $x_4$ and $y_2$. Only one of these will be tolerably close to $d_4$ and you will have found the approximate location of the point in question. If you wish to check the procedure for error reasons, you can compute again with a different set of $4$ known points or switch up which point you denote as $x_4$.